# Equation Interpretation

Tags: statistics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G706i.png)

Can anybody please explain the meaning of this equation?
I can figure out that it is the difference of the means, but really can't get what each of these components mean...

Comment: Please format your question using MathJax.

Comment: For the most helpful answer, it would help if you provided some context and explained the parts of the notation you do understand.